# Printwindow prints with empty space

Tags: winapi, gdi, user32

The width and height of application Melon is 438 x 615 pixels and ::GetWindowRect() function grab it correctly.

However, ::PrintWindow() function draws smaller size which is 348 x 489 pixels, rest of them filled with black blank(may be draw nothing)

...may the one picture will be better than hundreds of discription.

here is result of the code

[image]

```
bool result = true;

HWND appHWnd = ::FindWindow(nullptr, TEXT("Melon"));

RECT appWindowRect; ::GetWindowRect(appHWnd, &appWindowRect);
HDC appDC = ::GetWindowDC(appHWnd);
//    HDC appDC = ::GetDC(appHWnd); // same issue occured either
//    HDC appDC = ::GetDC(nullptr);
HDC memoryDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(appDC);

HBITMAP capturedScreenBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(
    appDC,
    appWindowRect.right - appWindowRect.left,
    appWindowRect.bottom - appWindowRect.top
);

HBITMAP memoryBitmap = static_cast<HBITMAP>(::SelectObject(memoryDC, capturedScreenBitmap));

result = ::PrintWindow(appHWnd, memoryDC, 0);

//copy to clipboard
OpenClipboard(nullptr);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, capturedScreenBitmap);
CloseClipboard();

::SelectObject(memoryDC, memoryBitmap);
::DeleteObject(capturedScreenBitmap);
::DeleteDC(memoryDC);
::ReleaseDC(appHWnd, appDC);
```

Strangely, C# version of the code works correctly. import same user32 library, use same of it and output different result? why?

Comment: You should unselect the `HBITMAP` from `memoryDC` before giving it to the clipboard, but more importantly DO NOT delete the `HBITMAP` after giving it to the clipboard! `SetClipboardData()` takes ownership, it does not make a copy. This is clearly explained in the `SetClipboardData()` documentation. Also, calling `OpenClipboard()` will a null `HWND` is also an error mentioned in the `SetClipboardData()` documentation. Don't do it.

Comment: i found that difference between C and C# is not ::PrintWindow but ::GetWindowRect. i dunno why...

Comment: It will be down to DPI awareness

Comment: @David Heffernan exactly correct. thank you!

Comment: @user3244483 You can answer your own question and provide a solution for help others are searching on this issue.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT  that's not bad advice

Answer (score 0):

It will be down to DPI awareness – David Heffernan

::GetWindowRect, which used to c# project and C++ console project in Visual Studio, aren't  affected from the scaling by dpi awareness. but, what used to qt studio are affected from it.

here is my solution.

```
RECT appWindowRect; {
    ::GetWindowRect(hwnd, &appWindowRect);
}

POINT appWindowSize; {
    qreal dotsPerInch = QApplication::screens().at(0)->logicalDotsPerInch();
    appWindowSize.x = static_cast<LONG>((appWindowRect.right - appWindowRect.left) * 96 / dotsPerInch);
    appWindowSize.y = static_cast<LONG>((appWindowRect.bottom - appWindowRect.top) * 96 / dotsPerInch);
}
```